# Security concerns when storing objects in session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I am working on a project where I have to interface with a web service that I do not control. The service does not support any sort of token based authentication. Unfortunately our use cases require that the user interacts with the service at various points in time while interacting with our website. Security concerns make it so that I cannot store the users credentials in the session. I have some questions about the use of Session State in this kind of scenario. Specifically, how exactly does session state store a complex object? If I store the entire connection object (which includes the credentials) in the session, is there a risk that a session compromise could lead to an attacker getting the actual credentials?

Comment: nope its stored based on the session provider.

Comment: Are you expecting `Session hijacking attack`

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Actually you no need to store connection object, I guess you can just create cookies and handle it based on you requirements and dispose it on time or event basis.

Comment: Session hijack attack is always a risk. The risk I am trying to mitigate is the actual credential (which could be used to access other resources) does not get compromised. Daniel A. White - is this documented anywhere? I'd like to be able to point to a resource that definitively explains why this is the case.